# How to use expression in in ngModel of Angular 5

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

My main component:

```
import { SingleTenant } from './single-tenant';

export class TenantStructure {
  roomNum: number;
  tenant1: SingleTenant;
  tenant2: SingleTenant;
  tenant3: SingleTenant;
  tenant4: SingleTenant;
  advanceAmount: number;
  rentAmount: number;
  electricityBill: number;
  miscAmount: number;
  empty: string;
}
```

**SingleTenant** Class:

```
export class SingleTenant {  
  name: string;  
  number: string;  
}
```

**HTML** Code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of tenantsInRoom | fill">  
  <td>Name: <input type="text"  
  [(ngModel)]="newRoomData.tenant{{x}}.name"></td>  
</tr>
```

`[(ngModel)]="newRoomData.tenant{{x}}.name"` is giving an error.

Here `{{x}}` can be between `1-4` and I want to add the details for `tenant1/tenant2/tenant3/tenant4`

Comment: Would `newRoomData['tenant' + x].name` work?

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for your suggestion i thought that object[key] = value works only in script.
It works